# Checkbox Check to specify the field you want to update

Tags: php, xhtml

Can you please enlighten me and give some ideas!
I can view my data from the database and insert a data into my DB.
Now all i want is to have a checkbox in each field, if i SELECT all my data and view it in a table, I will choose or check the field that i want to edit or to delete and click the button to pass the selected field into my edit form..

So how can i pass the value of the checkbox to the edit button?

Answer (score 0):

When you post data to server if check box is clicked then value of check box is posted to server and you can find it in post data by its name, for e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="chkEmail" />
```

in php you can get it this way

```
$_POST['chkEmail']
```

so on server side you can solve your problem like this

```
if(isset($_POST['chkEmail']))
   updateEmail();
```

and do this for your every property, you can update each column with single query, or you can build query for update.

Comment: Gracias! i will try this one.